# How to fill up the height within an object

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want a page that has two fixed-width columns on the left and a main column that fills up the rest of the width of `<body>`. Within each column, I want to place some `<div>` object on the top and  a `<ul>` object that fills up the rest of the height. I tried the following, but could not make the height of the `<ul>` objects automatically adjust to fill in the height. Rather, it overflows to the bottom as much as the height of the `<div>` above them.

```
<html>
<style>
body{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
.column{
    float: left;
    background-color:blue;
}
.column>ul{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
#main-column>ul{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color:brown;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="column">
  <div>Column 1 Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>Column 2 Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main-column">
  <div>Main Column Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

How can I make it so that height of the `<ul>` objects are automatically adjusted to fill up the remaining height?
    ​
This is what I get so far. The scroll bar is cut off and extends below the window border, which indicates that its height is overflowing.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the column titles a fixed height, you can use that along with `position: absolute` on the `ul`s to get the layout you want.  Demo: http://jsbin.com/ecilob/1/edit

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="column fw">
        <div class="title">Column 1 Title</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column fw">
        <div class="title">Column 2 Title</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column main">
        <div class="title">Main Column Title</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.column .title { 
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
}

.column {
  background: lightblue;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.column + .column {
  background: coral;
  left: 120px;
}
.column + .column + .column { background: goldenrod; }

.column.fw {
  width: 120px;
}
.column.main {
  left: 240px;
  right: 0;
}

.column ul {
 position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```